# script notify node down

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that sends an email when one of my DRBD nodes down, this script runs every 4mn, the problem is when one of the nodes fails (down) the script keeps sending emails every 4mn, how can I make the script only send once a day, or every 24 hours?.

I post the current script.

```
#!/bin/sh
NOTIFY_EMAIL="ray@superdomain.com"
SENDMAIL="/opt/zimbra/common/sbin/sendmail"
SUBJECT="Nodo Cluster DRBD Down"
status=$(egrep "(Connected)" /proc/drbd |wc -l)

if [ ! $status -eq 1 ] ; then
  echo -e "Subject: $SUBJECT\nFrom: ROBOT@$HOSTNAME\n$HOSTNAME DRBD Alert\nDate:`date`\n\n `/usr/sbin/pcs status` "| $SENDMAIL $NOTIFY_EMAIL
fi
```

Comment: Please paste the actual code.

Comment: So there is no actual issue with your code? You just need an opinion when to run it??

Comment: Sorry if I'm not making myself understood, that script works, if one of my nodes goes down, it sends the notification, the problem is that this script is in a crontab task and runs every 4 minutes, I'm receiving the notification every 4 minutes, I just want the notification to be sent once a day.

Comment: Just write the time of the last notification into a file. Then either only send if the time is more than one day ago or even optimise further by changing the next crontab schedule time.

Comment: Question was closed while writing an answer. Short version: Use a suitable file to hold a time stamp `TIMESTAMPFILE="/var/tmp/myscript.mail.sent"`. Wrap sending mail in an additional check `if [ -z $(find "$TIMESTAMPFILE" -mtime 0 2>/dev/null) ] ; then touch "$TIMESTAMPFILE"; echo ...|sendmail ... ; fi`. Explanation: `find "$TIMESTAMPFILE" -mtime 0` prints file name if the modification time is less than 24 hours ago. If the file does not exist or is older, the output will be empty. Tested with `if [ -z $(...) ]`. `touch ...` creates the file or updates the modification time when sending mail.)

Comment: I don't know why, modify my question ...

Comment: It got closed 8 minutes before the edit; that said: the behaviour has nothing to do with the actual script as such, but with the logic around `cron` and notifications.

Comment: do I have to reopen this question?

Comment: @rickygm I modified the question to make it clear why you (may) want to change the interval for the mail but not the interval for the check. This was how I understood the question. I'm sorry if this was not what you want. My edit was an attempt to improve the question in order to get it reopened. I voted to reopen it. You removed this explanation with your last edit. Without an explanation why you want to limit the sending of the mail but keep the short interval for the check, there is little chance to get it reopened. My proposed solution is a bit hard to read in my previous comment.

Comment: thank Bodo for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep doing the check every 4 minutes, but suppress repeated mails for the same day or for 24 hours, you have to save the time when you sent the mail.

You can use the modification time of a file for this purpose.

```
#!/bin/sh
NOTIFY_EMAIL="ray@superdomain.com"
SENDMAIL="/opt/zimbra/common/sbin/sendmail"
SUBJECT="Nodo Cluster DRBD Down"

TIMESTAMPFILE="/var/tmp/myscript.mail.sent"

status=$(egrep "(Connected)" /proc/drbd |wc -l)

if [ ! $status -eq 1 ] ; then
  if [ -z $(find "$TIMESTAMPFILE" -mtime 0 2>/dev/null) ] ; then
    touch "$TIMESTAMPFILE"
    echo -e "Subject: $SUBJECT\nFrom: ROBOT@$HOSTNAME\n$HOSTNAME DRBD Alert\nDate:`date`\n\n `/usr/sbin/pcs status` "| $SENDMAIL $NOTIFY_EMAIL
  fi
fi
```

This version will suppress the mail for 24 hours.

**Explanation:**

`find "$TIMESTAMPFILE" -mtime 0` prints the file name if the file exists and its modification time stamp is less than 24 hours ago. If the file does not exist or is older, the output will be empty.

Test for empty output with `if [ -z $(find ...) ]` means no mail has been sent recently or the state is unknown (no file).

`touch "$TIMESTAMPFILE"` creates the file or updates the modification time to save the time when the mail was sent.

If you want to suppress the mail for the current calendar day instead of 24 hours, you can add option `-daystart` to the `find` command.

```
  if [ -z $(find "$TIMESTAMPFILE" -daystart -mtime 0 2>/dev/null) ] ; then
```